# Acknowledged messages getting retried

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Google Pub/Sub ruby client to process messages sent to multiple topics. For each message received, I enqueue it using ActiveJob and acknowledge it to mark it as processed.

```rb
subscription.listen do |msg|
  Rails.logger.debug("Processing message with id #{msg.message_id}")

  MyJob.perform_later(JSON.parse(msg.data))
  msg.acknowledge!
  
  Rails.logger.debug("ACKed message with id #{msg.message_id}")
end
```

However, by checking the logs I see that messages that had already been acknowledged are being processed once and again (see extract from logs):

```
2021-05-04 02:15:17.089 EDT "Processing message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:15:17.180 EDT "ACKed message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:17:58.121 EDT "Processing message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:17:58.186 EDT "ACKed message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:20:59.899 EDT "Processing message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:20:59.985 EDT "ACKed message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:22:21.083 EDT "Processing message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:22:21.394 EDT "ACKed message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:24:18.389 EDT "Processing message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:24:18.485 EDT "ACKed message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:25:54.274 EDT "Processing message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:25:54.385 EDT "ACKed message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:26:59.087 EDT "Processing message with id 2260372604401883"
2021-05-04 02:26:59.184 EDT "ACKed message with id 2260372604401883"
```

The number of unacked messages reported by Google is dramatically increasing, so I suspect that the `acknowledge!` method is not behaving as expected.

- Ruby version: 2.6.6
- `google-cloud-pubsub` version: 2.6.1 (latest)

Comment: Could you provide more information about your architecture/scenario? Some details about process overview? Why are you using multiple topics? Are the messages sent to each topic different? Each subscriber should ack the received message like mentioned in [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber) If you have multiple topics with the same message, each topic's subscription should ack the message, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We are using multiple topics to separate events by business meaning. For example, when a payment has happened, we post a message in `payment-complete` topic, and when an account is created we post a message in `account-created` topic. A message only belongs to one topic, it is never shared across topics.

About the architecture, this project is subscribed to ~40 topics. The snippet provided is included in a loop, so we configure that callback (enqueue and ACK) for each of the subscriptions.

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen this problem before, but I can suggest a few things to try:

1. Log the subscriber ack deadline to make sure it allows enough time for `MyJob.perform_later` to return. This is really just a sanity check since it's most likely the default 60 seconds, but you might as well check.
2. Configure an error handler on the subscriber:

```
subscriber = subscription.listen do |msg|
  # process message
  msg.acknowledge!
end

Rails.logger.debug("subscriber ack deadline: #{subscriber.deadline}")

# Register to be notified when unhandled errors occur.
subscriber.on_error do |error|
  Rails.logger.error(error.message)
end
```

3. Configure gRPC debug logging.  The generic logger configuration instructions are in [LOGGING.md](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-pubsub/LOGGING.md). To adapt them to Rails you can place the following in `config/initializers/grpc_logging.rb`:

```rb
module MyLogger
  def logger
    Rails.logger
  end
end

# Define a gRPC module-level logger method before grpc/logconfig.rb loads.
module GRPC
  extend MyLogger
end
```